# Can APNS token be used by other apps to send notification?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have an app A which is registered to apple to receive notifications and this generates "tokenA" which is passed to "providerA".

Now there is a another app B which is registered to apple to receive notifications and this generates "tokenB which is passed to "providerB".

So if "providerB" somehow gets hold of "tokenA" can "providerB" exploit the "tokenA" to send span messages to app A using "tokenA" ?

because both providerA and providerB has access to connect to apple servers.

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember, the connection to the APNS server is over SSL with an application-specific certificate - so unless provider B also gets hold of the certificate, they shouldn't be able to send notifications.

I could be misremembering the certificate part, admittedly.